# Steam looks messed up

Tags: gpu, amd-graphics, steam, games, fullscreen

Running Pop OS on an Intel Hades Canyon. Just installed Steam and it looks like this:

[image]

Restarting the computer or reinstalling Steam from different sources did not solve the issue. Wierd enough, if I go full screen with Steam it looks okay, but if I resize the window it looks messed up again. Drivers seem fine, what else could it be?

This is what the output of `lspci -v -s 01:00.0` looks like:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Polaris 22 XT [Radeon RX Vega M GH] (rev c0) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Polaris 22 XT [Radeon RX Vega M GH]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 148
    Memory at 2000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4G]
    Memory at 2100000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at db500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

If I run Steam from terminal, the same problem happens and no useful information is returned to stdout.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Could you try running `steam` in terminal? Do you get any output?

Comment: Welcome, as mentioned we don't have any valuable info from you, I will vote to close if not fixed soon.

Comment: Hi @Rayleigh, nothing useful is printed to stdout unfortunately. Added that info plus the output of lspci -v -s 01:00.0 to the original question, let me know if I can provide you with any other additional information.

Comment: I *think* Steam uses Wine and OpenGL. Are you able to try other apps that use either or both of those?

Comment: Are you using a compositing window manager? Are you able to disable compositing?

Comment: Can you search the [steam-for-linux issue tracker](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues)? This seems similar to https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/6593

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled in Steam? Does it still happen if you use default Steam settings? (e.g. by renaming the Steam config data directory)

Comment: Hi @Mikel, thanks for the pointers. My issue is exactly the same as in that thread you share, well spot. I updated the client to the latest beta version and that solved the issue. Are you okay to move that recommendation into an actual answer so that I can mark the question as answered? Thanks again for the help, made my day.

Comment: Done! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue sounds similar to https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/6593 - steam view becomes corrupted when resizing in a tiling window manager

The title is a bit misleading: further down the bug report they say it happens if Steam hardware acceleration is enabled, even if you're not using a tiling window manager.

It is supposed to be fixed in the latest Steam beta.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same system and it is not steam related. You have to disable the igpu in the bios settings and everything will work fine. Intel also suggests to disable the igpu when installing linux in this system to avoid problems.